# Visualising a 1-(50,15,15) design.

Tags: visualization, mathematica, combinatorial-designs

The problem I have is the visualisation of a 1-(50,15,15) design. That is a set of 50 points and 50 blocks (lines), so that each point is on 15 lines, and each line contains 15 points.

My attempts thus far have been on Mathematica. I have managed to create a graph with 50 points and 750 edges, so obviously the problem is putting 15 points on a given edge.

Comment: Mathematica, is my preferred option to visualise this. The main problem being I don't know how to use the graph function so that edges contain multiple vertices.

Comment: Have you tried Mathematica SE?

Comment: I have upon your suggestion, no replies yet.

Comment: http://www.mathpuzzle.com/5config2.gif  has 48 points with 5 lines go through every point, and 5 points are on every line. Based on http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_17/PDF/v17i1r2.pdf . You won't be able to use straight lines, but you can use splines.  It would help to see your data.

Answer (score 1):

A graph by definition has only two vertices on each edge, so I don't think you can use the "graph" object in Mathematica to model this (at least not in this way).

You can do a bipartite graph with one part corresponding to the points and another to the blocks.  So you will have 100 vertices total, and the graph will be $15$-regular.